# Updated Proof from previous question

Tags: linear-algebra

After realizing my proof was incorrect, I tried it again.

**Question:**

If $L : V \rightarrow W$ is a linear mapping and ${L(v_1), . . . , L(v_n)}$ is linearly independent,
then {v1, . . . , vn} is linearly inddependent.

I tried using a contradiction, but I feel like I made a mistake again (in a similar way).

**1.** Assume ${v_1,…,v_n}$ is linearly dependent. Then for the equation

$c_1v_1 + ... + c_n v_n = 0 $**(1)**

there exists a non-trivial solution.

**2.** Since zero vector maps to zero vectors in linear mappings, we have

$L(c_1 v_1 + .... + c_n v_n) = 0$ **(2)**

$c_1L(v_1) + ... + c_nL(v_n) = 0$ **(3)**

where at least one of $c_1,c_2 ... c_n$ is non zero.

This is a contradiction ...

But I feel like I made a mistake when going from equation **1** to equation **2** because since we put $"c_1v_1 + ... + c_n v_n$ into a different context (inside a linear mapping), the $c_1, c_2, ..., c_n$ can now hold different values and we are not guaranteed to have at least one c != 0.

Comment: But $L$ is linear, so you can do that.

Comment: I'm talking about going from 1 to 2, not 2 to 3.

Comment: Why can't you plug things in to functions?  That's perfectly normal/acceptable/the point.

Comment: I'm saying, couldn't the values of c1, ..., cn change since I'm plugging it into a function?

Comment: When you have $x=3$ and plug it into $f(x)=x^2$, does the $3$ change from the time you set it as $x$ to when you decided to plug it in?  $f(3)=3^2=9$.

Comment: Wow it s such a simple explanation, but so hard for me to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Tip:  if something is easy, let it be easy!